# surface area of $\left\{(x,y,z)\in R^3\,\mid\, x^2+y^2 =\frac{1}{z^2}, 1<z<3\right\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I want to calculate the surface area of the surface that bounds the solid $$K=\left\{(x,y,z)\in R^3\,\mid\, x^2+y^2 \leq\frac{1}{z^2},   1<z<3\right\}$$

I'm stuck with the differential surface area that I shall consider so that I can solve $S=\iint dS$.

Comment: Your surface can be parametrized in cylindrical coordinates as $(\frac{1}{z},\theta,z)$ with $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$ and $z\in(1,3)$.

Comment: so as a result ill get that S= $\int_1^3 \frac{1}{z} dz$

Comment: @symplectomorphic: Your parametrization is incorrect. It should be $(\frac{\cos\theta}{z},\frac{\sin\theta}{z},z)$.

Comment: @Kuifje: my parametrization isn't incorrect; you're just reading it incorrectly. I gave the cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I believe it is incorrect. If you can find the surface area with your parametrization I will take that away.

Comment: @Kuifje My parametrization says exactly what yours says, because in polar $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, and here $r=\frac{1}{z}$. I just didn't write the parametrization with the image in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I understand your logic, but I would not know how to use this parametrization to find the surface area, as it is not equal to 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3 || r_z\times r_{\theta}|| \;dzd\theta
$$

Comment: @Kuifje: It is an elementary calculation using the differential geometry of cylindrical coordinates. I will post a complete answer when I have time this evening. Of course, it winds up giving the same integral you describe in the second half of your answer. But I like that there is no need to pass through Cartesian coordinates (except only implicitly).

Comment: Great! The more alternatives the better.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: Just for the record, using cartesian coordinates for parametrizing has the following advantage: computing $r_x\times r_y$ is always very easy when $x$ and $y$ are the parameters, as vectors $r_x$ and $r_y$ both have $0$'s and $1$'s for two of its components. I always recommend doing it this way, even if it means performing a change of variables once the integral is correctly set.

Comment: @Kuifje: what I wrote yesterday was nonsense; I've posted a correct answer. I like this approach not because it is faster than using $(x,y,z)$ coordinates but because it requires one to think carefully about alternative coordinate systems. Plus, it shows that one does not need to use $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

The surface can be parametrized as follows 
\begin{cases}
x=x\\
y=y\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(x,y)\in D=\{(x,y)\;|\;\frac{1}{9}\le x^2+y^2\le 1\}\\
z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
\end{cases}

You can plot this surface and its domain $D$ with WolframAlpha:

[image]

Now, the surface area is given by
$$
A=\iint_D ||r_x\times r_y ||\; dA = \iint_{\{(x,y)\;|\;\frac{1}{9}\le x^2+y^2\le 1\}} \sqrt{ \frac{x^2+y^2+(x^2+y^2)^3}{(x^2+y^2)^3}}\; dA 
$$

Switching to polar coordinates yields:
$$
\boxed{
A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{1/3}^1\sqrt{r^{-2}+r^2}\; drd\theta \approx  7.6030
}
$$

**Alternatively** you could proceed as follows:
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{\cos\theta}{z}\\
y=\frac{\sin\theta}{z}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad0\le \theta\le 2\pi, \; 1\le z\le 3\\
z=z\\
\end{cases}
$$
A=\iint_{\{(\theta,z)|0\le\theta\le 2\pi, \; 1\le z\le 3\}} ||r_{\theta}\times r_z ||\; dA 
$$
Computing the integral yields
$$
\boxed{A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3\sqrt{z^{-2}+z^{-6}}\;dzd\theta \approx  7.6030}
$$

Also note that using the change of variables $z=\frac{1}{r}$ (i.e., $dz=\frac{-dr}{r^2}=-z^2dr$):
$$
\int_{1/3}^1\sqrt{r^{-2}+r^2}\; dr = \int_1^3\sqrt{z^{-2}+z^{-6}}\;dz
$$

Comment: The first image is imprecise, it shows the 'lower part' of the surface clipped at $|x|=1$ and $|y|=1$ whilst the problem defines clippping at $z=1$.

Comment: The way I see it is the surface ranges from $z=1$ to $3$ with $-1\le x,y\le 1$, which gives a "trimmed volcano" as @Zubzub mentioned. We don't really need the picture for calculations anyway.

Comment: This being said I dont understand why results with @Zubzub don't match (his integral equals $\approx 13.48$). They should, his method looks correct as well.

Comment: But then where did i go wrong when i say r=$\frac{1}{z}$ and solving S=$\iint ds$ considering ds=$r d\theta dz$?

Comment: You would need to compute it with $dA = || r_z\times r_\theta|| d\theta dz \neq r d\theta dz $

Comment: I considered an infinitisemal ring of such surface area, wouldnt that cover the whole surface after integration?

Comment: If your variables are $\theta$ and $z$, then what is $r$ in your $rd\theta dz$ ?

Comment: 2 sides of the infinitesimal surface,  the first one is $rd \theta$ the second is its  small hight $dz$

Comment: So your $r$ is fixed? If it is not, there should be a $dr$ somewhere.

Comment: r depending on z and equals $\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42076/discussion-between-kuifje-and-mohamad-misto).

Comment: Parameterisation need not have $t$? Like $x=t$, $y=s$ and $z=(t^2 + s^2)^{-1/2}$

Comment: You can use the parameters that you like, it will not change anything. Parameters are just symbols that we manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Kuifje wonders in the comments how to calculate the surface area using the cylindrical parametrization $r(s,t)=t^{-1}$, $\theta(s,t)=s$, $z(s,t)=t$ for $(s,t)\in(0,2\pi)\times(1,3)$.

I admit this approach is hard to find in most multivariable calculus texts (feel free to speculate why it is more likely to be found in a physics book), but the procedure is the same: we cross tangent vectors to get the normal surface element, and then integrate its magnitude over the specified region in $(s,t)$ space. There are two catches. First, the position vector in cylindrical coordinates is not $r\mathbf{\hat{r}}+\theta\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}+z\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ but rather $r\mathbf{\hat{r}}+z\mathbf{\hat{z}}$. (Similarly, the position vector in polar coordinates is not $r\mathbf{\hat{r}}+\theta\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ but simply $r\mathbf{\hat{r}}$.) Second, writing down tangent vectors is not as simple as in Cartesian coordinates, because the basis vectors in cylindrical coordinates change from point to point. But these are important features of curvilinear coordinate systems, so it is important to be fluent with them.

I will give the argument for a general parametrization $\mathbf{u}(s,t)=r\mathbf{\hat{r}}+z\mathbf{\hat{z}}$, where $r$, $\theta$, and $z$ depend on $s$ and $t$, and then apply it to the special case above.

Partial differentiating the position vector with respect to $s$ and $t$ gives our tangent vectors

$$\mathbf{u}_s=r_s\mathbf{\hat{r}}+r\color{red}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial s}}+z_s\mathbf{\hat{z}}+z\color{red}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial s}}$$

and

$$\mathbf{u}_t=r_t\mathbf{\hat{r}}+r\color{blue}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial t}}+z_t\mathbf{\hat{z}}+z\color{blue}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial t}}$$

To calculate the partial derivatives of the basis vectors with respect to $s$ and $t$ (in red and blue), we must use the chain rule. Without loss of generality, I illustrate just for $s$:

$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial s}}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial r}r_s+\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial\theta}\theta_s+\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial z}z_s$$

and

$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial s}}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial r}r_s+\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial\theta}\theta_s+\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial z}z_s$$

But in cylindrical coordinates we have $\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial z}=\mathbf{0}$ and $\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial z}=\mathbf{0}$, while $\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial\theta}=\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$, so

$$\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{\partial s}=\theta_s\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}},\,\,\frac{\partial\mathbf{\hat{z}}}{\partial s}=\mathbf{0}$$

Substituting into our expressions for the tangent vectors, we have

$$\boxed{\mathbf{u}_s=r_s\mathbf{\hat{r}}+r\theta_s\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}+z_s\mathbf{\hat{z}}}$$

and

$$\boxed{\mathbf{u}_t=r_t\mathbf{\hat{r}}+r\theta_t\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}+z_t\mathbf{\hat{z}}}$$

This may look like a lot of work, but for someone well-versed in vector analysis, this is common knowledge and can easily be looked up.

For the special case $r(s,t)=t^{-1}$, $\theta(s,t)=s$, and $z=t$, we get

$$\mathbf{u}_s=t^{-1}\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}},\,\,\mathbf{u}_t=-t^{-2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}+\mathbf{\hat{z}}$$

Crossing these gives our surface element

$$\mathbf{u}_s\times\mathbf{u}_t=t^{-1}\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}\times\big(-t^{-2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}+\mathbf{\hat{z}}\big)=t^{-1}(\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}\times\mathbf{\hat{z}}}_{=\mathbf{\hat{r}}})-t^{-3}(\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}\times\mathbf{\hat{r}}}_{=-\mathbf{\hat{z}}})=\boxed{t^{-1}\mathbf{\hat{r}}+t^{-3}\mathbf{\hat{z}}}$$

The magnitude of this vector is $\sqrt{t^{-2}+t^{-6}}$, and integrating this function over the region $(s,t)\in(0,2\pi)\times(1,3)$ gives our surface area, the same result as Kuifje's second approach:

$$\boxed{\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3\sqrt{t^{-2}+t^{-6}}\,dt\,ds\approx 7.6030}$$

Comment: Nice work. I take back what I said.

Comment: Let me remark that even though in this approach I used the Christoffel symbols for cylindrical coordinates in the Euclidean flat connection to derive the tangent vectors from the position vector (for that is what differentiating the basis vectors amounts to), we actually do not need to invoke the connection explicitly, nor do we need to speak of a position vector (a concept which makes sense only in Euclidean space and does not generalize to the setting of arbitrary manifolds). The tangent vectors are determined by the metric & the diffeomorphism giving the change of coordinates. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) In any coordinate system $(q^1, q^2, q^3)$ the tangent vector takes the form $\sum\dot{q}^i\mathbf{q_i}$ where the $\mathbf{q_i}$ are the basis vectors induced by the change of coordinates. But these vectors may not be normalized; we correct for that using the scale factors $h_i=\|\mathbf{q_i}\|$ given by the metric, so the tangent vector becomes $\dot{q}^ih_i\mathbf{\hat{q}_i}$. In the case of cylindrical coordinates, $h_r=h_z=1$ but $h_\theta=r$ so the tangent vector has the form $$\dot{r}\mathbf{\hat{r}}+r\dot{\theta}\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}+\dot{z}\mathbf{\hat{z}}$$